# GLSL - Uniform error

Tags: opengl, glsl

I wrote shaders in `#version 150`. I have problem with uniforms. If I use any of light uniforms (vec4) my scene disappears.

Extraction of setting uniforms:

```
typedef struct { float x, y, z, w; } vec4;
//...
class MyClass {
    GLuint _id;
    vec4 light_diffuse;
};
//...
void MyClass::setUniforms {
    //...
    GLint location = glGetUniformLocation(_id, "in_light_diffuse");
    //...
    glUseProgram(_id);
    //...
    glUniform4fv(location, 1, (const GLfloat *)&light_diffuse);
    //...
}
```

THIS WORKS:

```
#version 150

in vec4 in_vertex;
in vec3 in_normal;
in vec4 in_color;

uniform mat4 in_mvp_matrix;

uniform vec4 in_light_position;
uniform vec4 in_light_ambient;
uniform vec4 in_light_diffuse;
uniform vec4 in_light_specular;

out vec4 v_color;

void main() {
    //vec4 a = in_light_position + in_light_ambient + in_light_diffuse + in_light_specular;
    v_color = in_color;
    gl_Position = in_mvp_matrix * in_vertex;
}
```

THIS **DOESN'T** WORK:

```
#version 150

in vec4 in_vertex;
in vec3 in_normal;
in vec4 in_color;

uniform mat4 in_mvp_matrix;

uniform vec4 in_light_position;
uniform vec4 in_light_ambient;
uniform vec4 in_light_diffuse;
uniform vec4 in_light_specular;

out vec4 v_color;

void main() {
    vec4 a = in_light_position + in_light_ambient + in_light_diffuse + in_light_specular;
    v_color = in_color;
    gl_Position = in_mvp_matrix * in_vertex;
}
```

In first case I can see colorful objects, but in the second everything disappears. I don't even use these uniforms for calculation `out_flag_color` and result is empty screen.

It's simple. If I use one of them (no matter for what) it's empty.

Anybody help?

Comment: How are you performing the lighting calculations, and where?

Comment: There are not calculations yet. I can't even set 'out_frag_color' to any of light colors. They are empty or something. I can't calculate lighting, because every result is blank scene.

Comment: Okay. Read my question one more time, I write basically constant diffuse color, for example `vec4(1, 0, 0, 1)` to `out_frag_color` (pixel output) through varying variable `v_color`, nothing more (`out_frag_color = v_color = in_light_diffuse`). And there is blank scene. Color from attribute `out_frag_color = v_color = in_color` works fine, objects are colorful and visible.

Comment: I think you didn't get what is problem. I have grey context background. I would be really happy, if I see black (default light value) objects. But there is nothing. It's not black, it's blank, empty. If my color attributes work, and light color is zero, then line  `v_color = in_color + in_light_diffuse;` should be the same color value as `in_color`, but it's not. There is nothing. Everything disappears.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70183/discussion-between-eseverus-and-poriferous).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I was setting `vec4` to `uniform mat4` location.